# CustomUser has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using jwt auth system When I fill the field it returns jwt token easily but if i want to create a profile with this token it says

> CustomUser has no attribute 'objects'

my **users/models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, unique=True)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
   date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

   object = UserManager()

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(CustomUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
      return self
```

and **user/views.py**

```
class CreateUserAPIView(APIView):
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

def post(self, request):
    user = request.data
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=user)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()

    try:
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']

        user = CustomUser.object.get(email=email, password=password)
        if user:
            try:
                payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
                token = jwt.encode(payload, settings.SECRET_KEY)
                user_details = {}
                user_details['id'] = "%s" % (user.id)
                user_details['token'] = token
                user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__,
                                    request=request, user=user)
                return Response(user_details, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            except Exception as e:
                raise e
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
    except KeyError:
        res = {'error': 'please provide a email and a password'}
        return Response(res)
```

with this code I am getting a token but with this token I cannot create a profile

**profile/models.py**

```
class Profile(TimeModel):
   user = models.OneToOneField('user.CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
   birthdate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='path', null=True)

   def __str__(self):
     return self.user.email
```

here what i have tried so far. I tried to look for solution but could not get any and none of them solved my problems. How can I solve this problems. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

**P.S**
In the serializers file there is no additional overridden functions it just includes model name and fields of Profile model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a custom manager and you assign that to `object` instead of `objects` in your CustomUser model.

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    objects = UserManager()
    ...
```

Also, your queryset should use CustomUser.**objects**.get(...) Another thing I've realized is you're overriding the `save` method inside your `CustomUser` but you're not doing anything specific there, so there's no need to override that method.

Comment: now i have a new problem like null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains(smth, smth, null, null) can you tell me what does it mean?

Comment: Please update your question with your changes and also provide the traceback, error log so we can what's happening

Answer (score 1):

I think you've a typo in your code - it should be `objects`:

```
user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=email, password=password)
```